# Maven Version Order: 8.5.5.9 < 8.5.5?

Tags: maven

In Maven, is 8.5.5.9 an *earlier* version than 8.5.5?

I read that version numbers with more than two dots are treated "as strings" in comparison. What does this exactly imply?

Comment: did you read this [article from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm) ?

Comment: Yes, I did. If it answers my question, I didn't get it.

Comment: I agree. Look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13007017/1988304) .

Comment: which maven version shows this behaviour?